# Understanding convergence proof (Momentum algorithm)

Tags: optimization, mathematical-optimization, gradient-descent, convex-optimization, convergence

I am trying to understand the convergence analysis/derivation of the momentum algorithm, or the stochastic heavy ball algorithm, using the regret bound analysis from different research papers.

1. https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7330562 - Page3
2. https://www.mdpi.com/2504-3110/6/12/709 - Page6
3. http://arxiv.org/abs/1707.01647 - Page4

In the derivation, there is the following simplification, which I do not understand at all
[image: Concerned equation]

The term $\left|\boldsymbol{\theta}*{0} + \boldsymbol{p}*{0} - \boldsymbol{\theta}^* \right|^2 - \left|\boldsymbol{\theta}*{T+1} + \boldsymbol{p}*{T+1} - \boldsymbol{\theta}^*\right|^2$ is simplified to $\leq \left| \boldsymbol{\theta}_{0} - \boldsymbol{\theta}^* \right|^2$ directly. I am sure that there is certainly some assumption or some intermediate steps involved and the reader is supposed to know that. Could you please help me understand.

> My understanding:

[image: my understaning]

Comment: This is not a programming question. Please move it to Operations Research.